# how to add strings from dialog box in android?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, android-alertdialog

I need to add strings from alertdialog box to spinner at run time. Now i have the alertbox with an edittext and a button.please anyone help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in your onClickListener of your button in the allertdialog get the spinner element via finViewById and add the text to the spinner's adapter, e.g.:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("My Dialog");
builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int Id) {
            String value = input.getText().toString();
            Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.theSpinner);
            ArrayAdapter adapterForSpinner = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            mySpinner.setAdapter(adapterForSpinner);
            adapterForSpinner.add(value);
            return;
        }
    });
```

Hope my answer hits your problem.